# A URL is followed by number, what is its vulnerability?

Tags: http

A URL is followed by a number. Changing the number will change the content of the web page. Now I know it's insecure direct object reference (IDOR). What should I do to fix this vulnerability?
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: IDOR: Insecure direct object reference.

Comment: If access permissions are checked, and users does not see data for other users, enumeration need not be a vulnerability.

Comment: *"Changing the number will change the content of the web page."* - changing it to what? To an error message, to different payment information, to something else? This question is so far missing essential context.

Comment: The credit card number will change.

Answer (score 3):

This scenario you're describing sounds like a classic case of [Insecure Direct Object References](https://www.google.com/search?sca_esv=596200194&q=Insecure%20Direct%20Object%20References&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjetaX62ciDAxWl8gIHHbSmAXEQ0pQJegQIDBAB&biw=1920&bih=1053#imgrc=iOhKLuT2FcIy8M) (IDOR). This vulnerability occurs when an application provides direct access to objects based on user-supplied input. In your URL, the number you're referring to is an identifier that is directly changeable in the URL; so if the application does not properly verify that the user is authorized to access that object, then an attacker could potentially access unauthorized data. And, as a rule of thumb, don't expose direct references to database keys or other sensitive identifiers in the URL. That's just asking for trouble.

Refs:
https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/latest/4-Web_Application_Security_Testing/05-Authorization_Testing/04-Testing_for_Insecure_Direct_Object_References